# Extract column names dynamically without having to hardcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a admin page that displays all the tables from database. I want to do that without hardcoding the column names. Right now, I am hardcoding values in my view so it display values from the database table. How can I just extract the column names from the db without having to hardcode column names and just print them in table format. This way even if I have 10 tables, I can just call the table and print the column names extracting the information.

Here is the code:

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @products = Products.all
    end

end
```

View:

```
<h3 class="sub-header">Product</h3>
<table border='1' class="table table-striped" width="200">
    <tr class="success">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>url id</th>
        <th>price id</th>
    </tr>

<% @products.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><%= user.url %></td>
        <td><%= user.url_id %></td>
        <td><%= user.price_id %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the **column names** of a **model** using [`#column_names`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/column_names) like this:

```
<% User.column_names.each do |column| %>
  <%= column %>
<% end %>
```

You can use [`#attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes) to access **attributes** of an **object**, like this:

```
<% user.attributes.each do |name, value| %>
  <%= "#{name} : #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

---

So, the following snippet will serve your purpose:

```
<h3 class="sub-header">Product</h3>
<table border='1' class="table table-striped" width="200">
    <tr class="success">
      <% Doctor.column_names.each do |c| %>
        <th><%= c.upcase %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>

    <% @products.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <% user.attributes.each do |name, value| %>
          <td><%= value %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: What about column names, how to display them as headers to column values? if you notice in the above code that I got, I am hardcoding the column names <th>ID</th>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>url id</th>
        <th>price id</th>

Answer (score 1):

Use `Product.column_names`. So for your purpose,

```
<% Product.column_names.each do |column_name| %>
  <tr class="success">
    <th><%= column_name %></th>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a partial for this.

```
#eg in app/views/common/generic_table.html.erb
<%# expects a collection of the same type of object stored in `collection` %>
<% klass = collection.first.class %>
<% column_names = klass.column_names %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% column_names.each do |colname| %>
        <th><%= colname %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% collection.each do |obj| %>
      <tr>
        <% column_names.each do |colname| %>
          <td><%= obj.send(colname) %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now you can call this like

```
<%= render :partial => "common/generic_table", :locals => {:collection => @products} %>
```

or whatever else you have.